# Making a UITabView show the second level of a navigation controller by default

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

(Apologies for not being able to embed my images yet).

Using iOS storyboards, I have a UITabBarController with a UINavigation Controller/UITableView(1) embedded in it. This UITableView(1) then calls another UITableView(2):

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to make UITableView(2) appear when the Tab Bar is changed to that tab, and then have the UINavigationBar left arrow button exist to get back to UITableView(1).

The existing functionality I can think of which does this is the iPhone Mail app, where when you launch it you see your Inbox, and you can hit the left-arrow Mailboxes button to get back to your mail box list.

I've tried attaching the tab bar directly to UITableView(2) but it doesn't work as expected, there's no left arrow back button to get back to the previous view when the app is run.

I've also tried adding a navigation controller to that UITableView(2) and the Navigation controller correctly appears, but still without any back button:

[image]

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly new with storyboards and it's difficult to find what to search to get this working.

If it's not possible with just storyboards themselves, is there some kind of automatic (non-visible) push to the 2nd UITableView I could do?

Thanks!
Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing it the following way, as I wanted to perform the majority of the work within storyboards.

I set up the storyboard with the tab bar embedding the UINavigationController, which contained  UITableView(1) which then contained a custom segue to UITableView(2):

[image]

Then within the class associated with UITableView(1) I added this single line:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"campaigns" sender:self];
     ...
}
```

On load of the tab, the viewDidLoad of UITableView(1) instantly calls UITableView(2) without any kind of animation, showing the back button to UITableView(1), which is exactly what I wanted.

Thanks to those who responded!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will definitely help you : http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the delegate method as below.

`(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

In this method you can check for the tabBarController.selectedIndex or viewController object. This ensures the selection of correct tab , then push the controller having table 1, then push the controller having table 2.